# Problems with Curve Modifier (I tried all methods)

Tags: modifiers, curve-modifier

[image]

Hello. I need help. I try to roll my flat model by spiral with curve modifier. But it doesn’t work properly.

[image]

I’ve tried all the ways. I changed deform axis in curve modifier, aplied all transformations to spiral curve and to flat object, set up curve radius to 1, rotated origin curve and object. It all don’t work. I attached blend file. please help.

[image]

Comment: Could you provide your Blender file using https://blend-exchange.com/ instead of dropbox that requires login ?

Comment: @StefLAncien done

Answer (score 0):

*(Using Blender 3.6.8)*

#### First attempt

Assuming that the flat model should roll like a film, the first parameter to change is the curve *Tilt*, to set to 90°. Furthermore as the underlying *Plane* object is remaining flat, it is disconnected in the *Geometry Nodes* graph, to keep only the *box* instances and to produce the following result:

[image: Results]

Resources: [image]

#### Second attempt

Assuming that the flat model should remain flat and coplanar to the spiral, and that it should not be stretched radially, but only bended in the (X,Z) plane, the parameter to change is the *Curve Deform/Radius* parameter to uncheck in the curve *Object Data Properties* panel. Otherwise, the scale perpendicular to the curve tangent is modified. Furthermore, the flat model is scaled down to remove overlaps and to produce the following result:

[image: Without radius scaling]

Resources: [image]

Comment: ok. And what next? It still doesn't work.

Comment: you can see flat object at first picture. I need to curve it (to roll up) without any distortion

Comment: I try an other proposal, but I have to confess that as English is not my native language, I am facing difficulties to understand how to marry "curve & roll up" with "no distortion". If I am still far away, could you provide a sketch of what you are trying to produce ?